# Proper separation of concerns natively in node.js?

Tags: model-view-controller, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, separation-of-concerns

I am a total node.js noobie and trying to figure out the best way to structure my application with proper separation of concerns.

I am using mongodb via mongoose and have successfully gotten my controllers separated out using node.js modules and am trying to then separate out my models. What I've gone appears to work, but when I check the database nothing has been saved. Also, I tried a `console.log()` in the save function and nothing gets logged.

from my server.js I have:

```
app.post(api.urlslug + '/messages', messagesapi.insert);
```

I then have a /controllers/api/messages.js:

```
var m = require('../../models/message');

exports.index = function(req, res, next){
    res.send('all the messages...');
}

exports.insert = function(req, res, next){
    var message;
    message = new m.Message({
        messagebody: req.body.messagebody
    });
    message.save(function(err) {
        console.log('here we are in the save');
        if(!err) {
            return console.log('message created');
        } else {
            return console.log(err);
        }
    });
    return res.send(message);
}
```

and my /models/message.js looks like this:

```
// required modules
var mongoose = require('mongoose')
    , db = require('../models/db');

// setup database connection
mongoose.connect(db.connectionstring());

var Message = exports.Message = mongoose.model('Message', new mongoose.Schema({
    messagebody: String
}));
```

When I post to the API I get a the proper JSON back and it even has the _id field with what appears to me as a mongodb provided unique id. With that, I am having trouble understanding why it is not actually going into mongodb if it appears to be creating the object and communicating with mongodb correctly.

Comment: I'm not sure at first glance, but I think you might be wrong on 'and communicating with mongodb correctly'. More likely it hasn't communicated with MongoDB, but instead Mongoose has created the _id for you (yes it's able to do it, it's part of the beauty of Mongo's Objectid spec) Still, not sure what's going wrong. You're sure `exports.insert` is called? Moverover, how have you tested 'message' isn't persisted to MongoDB? Best way to check is using the Mongo CLI  on whatever platform you happen to be

Comment: @Geert-Jan That makes sense on the _id. That is very likely that it is mongoose creating the id. Yes, I checked the MongoDB using the Mongo CLI and no document are being created.

Comment: Could it be that the title of your question isn't actually what you are asking? You talk about separation of concerns but it seems your questions should be "Why isn't my MongoDB document being saved?"

Comment: @Pickels I don't think that would be exactly accurate because if I drop all of this into a single file it writes to the MongoDB server just fine. So, my issues is when I try to break out into proper separation of concerns. I don't know if I am doing that part correctly.

Comment: I don't know MongoDB myself the only thing I see is that you do `return res.send(message);` outside your save callback.

Answer (score 0):

sounds like a connection is not being made. try listening to the open/error events of the default mongoose connection to find out why.

```
function log (msg) { console.log('connection: ', msg) }
mongoose.connection.on('open', log);
mongoose.connection.on('error', log);
```